# How to change this async pipe and take value directly?

Tags: angular, typescript, async-pipe

My compomnet.tx file had some store subscribing method like below.

```
readonly selectedId$: Observable<string | null> = this.store.select(selectedId)
    .pipe(shareReplayUntil(this.destroySub));
```

They are normally declared as variables. But I need to take this current value from them and pass it to another method in the same .ts file.

```
  onScanId() {
      // here I need to take subscribe id
      this.store.dispatch(scanId({ Id: "1" }));
  }
```

I need some expert help to resolve this. I prefer I can remove this read-only thing and assign it to directly variable, and use it in Html, the file also.
Currently, I take value using an async pipe, `{ selectedId$ | async }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is preventing you from just doing

```
  this.selectedId$.pipe(take(1)).subscribe(
    Id => this.store.dispatch(scanId({ Id }))
 )
```

you subscribe yo your observable using `take(1)` to get a single value and forget about it. then just subscribe to it, get the id and dispatch

Comment: whare i should put this code. it is ok to put normally as declar varible(i mean currunt read only deifnd place) or need to put thin in ngOnint ?

Comment: if value change, is it automatically update, has I subscribe the store? (sorry, I am abolute beginer)

Comment: this completely depend on what you want to do. I can't help you there much as it's dependend on your app and what you are doing.

 if you want always to scanid when Id change in the store, then remove `take(1)` and can put this in `constructor` or `ngOnInit`.  DO NOT FORGET to unsubscribe from it.

If you want it do to only once or in a specific method (like when you click a button, then put it in a specific method. and just call that method where you want like `onClick`

Comment: i tried your code in side scanId function but it given error like this 'Type 'string | null' is not assignable to type 'string'.
  Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string'''

Comment: i added addition if ,  if (Id) {} and wrote code, is it ok to fix it like that?

Comment: `selectedId$` is probably not always defined in your code. so yes you have to not dispatch the action if id is null. you can add a if there.